# shorting stock when you have no cash left in brockerage

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities

Is there any difference when shorting stock under the following 2 brokerage accounts?

1. $0 cash $50k in stocks
2. $50k cash $0 in stocks

Would you have to pay margin like longing a stock in scenario 1 since you have no money left?

Answer (score 1):

If the $50k worth of stocks are marginable securities then there is no difference between either scenario.  They are equal collateral.

When you short stock, you receive a credit in your account from the sale of the security.  You are not borrowing money from your broker so there is no margin interest.  However, there is a borrow fee which is paid to the lending broker, some of which may be shared with your broker and some brokers share a portion of the borrow fee with the owner of the loaned security.

Margin interest is constant.  Borrow fees can vary day to day, sometimes dramatically.

Comment: Interestingly, I haver never been charged anything for short selling shares (and buying them back after some days). Maybe the amount is too small and rounded to zero…

Comment: If the dollar value of the transaction was low and the borrow rate was minimal (the lowest I have seen is 25 BP) then it's possible that the total borrow cost was less than a penny a day.  But for a legit stock, say AAPL, GOOG, et al, it would be more significant.  Maybe it's possible that the broker eats a fee of a few pennies.

Comment: It was like several times a 100 AMZN and maybe 300 TSLA, for two to four days most times. So yes, significant volumes / values; but all as liquid and 'borrowable' as they come. Well, I'm thankful they were free. ;-)